# Azure DocumentDb continuation token

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using a continuation token to iterate over a result set in DocumentDb just fine, my intention is to expose the continuation token and the min/max page over a rest API via HATEOAS links so a user can run through all of their results.  Is there a potential security risk by returning the continuation token or the page ids?  Should I obfuscate them?  I would prefer to keep all the session state in the cosmos db and not have store the results somewhere else for pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a potential security risk by returning the continuation token or the page ids?

In my view, exposing the continuation token can not cause security issues. [continuation token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-response-headers) differs from [authorization token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN), a continuation token is returned from a query when there are additional results aside from what was returned in the response, normally clients resume query execution using the continuation token from the previous query to get additional results, and a continuation token that returned from the previous query cannot be used with a different query. If a client just get continuation token but do not have valid authorization token and do not know the query, the client can not get the results via that continuation token.

Comment: Very well, I was worried about exposing the min/max values, maybe I should just obfuscate those, I this they point to a specific document.  To your point though, they would need that authorization token to view the page so as long as that is never provided it should be secure.  I might choose to obfuscate just to hide the implementation.